# Unable to load data into BigQuery US Dataset, but can load into East-Asia Dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dataset

So the issue is, I am unable to load data to GCP BigQuery in dataset 'dw' located in US location. However I am able to load the data in East-Asia location.
I am trying to load data to partitioned tables in dataset 'dw' (US location) using NiFi ingestion tool but no error and no data loaded. I even tried inserting manually from BigQuery editor, unfortunately no error and no data inserted into dw.aes_mapdata2.

However, I am able to load data to dataset TEST.aes_mapdata2_copy which is in location "asia-east1".

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you do `create table dw.t1 as select 1 x`, could you get the table created with the 1 row of data?

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out. We had to create new tables. Seems we messed up the settings with the original tables we created.